# is there memory leak in this C++ code sample about pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I define one method to return reference. I know there is no any setence to delete pt, but when I run the code, it hints "~Object" be called. So is there any issue in this code? why I doesn't delete the pointer, but the deconstruter still be called? if be called, is there any memory issue in this case? 
Suppose the pointer and the reference both point one object, so one be deconstruter, is there need to delete the pointer?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Object.h"

using namespace std;

Object &testreturn(){
    Object *pt=new Object();
    return *pt;
}

int main() {
    Object o=testreturn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Please don't use pointers](http://klmr.me/slides/modern%2Dcpp.pdf). There's no need for them in your code snippet, you can just return the `pt` object. Even if `Object` is huge, virtually all compilers will do [return value optimization (RVO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) on it. Visual C++ will do RVO even if you explicitly turn off all optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a memory leak in this example. The problem is that your `o` object, which will be automatically deleted when it leaves scope, is a *copy* of the object allocated by your function. That original is still in memory waiting to be deleted.

That being said, there's no reason for this example to do a dynamic allocation. Instead, consider this:

```
Object testreturn(){
    Object pt;
    return pt;
}
```

Comment: While this won't cause memory leaks, you will return a dangling reference. Just return the object itself. Also, you have the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) going on here.

Comment: Your sample doesn't declare a object; it declares a function. lose the parens.

Comment: And now do what Insilico said. don't return a reference. return by-val. RVO will do the rest.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm researching that now, it's a new concept for me :)

Answer (score 2):

The destructor will be called, but only for one object of the two objects created in your sample code.

Here is what's going on:

- `testreturn` creates instance #1, and returns a reference to it
- `main` copies instance #1 into an instance #2
- A destructor for instance #2 gets called
- Instance #1 is leaked.